# iOS - How to apply gradient color to UICollectionViewCell backgroundView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, cagradientlayer

I have been able to apply the gradient I want to the backgroundView of my UICollectionViewCell. But every time I reload the cell, it applies again my gradient, accumulating all the gradient.

First of all here is my method for the gradient :

```
static func setGradientWhite(uiView: UIView) {

    let colorBottomWhite = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:0.30).cgColor
    let colorTopWhite = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:0).cgColor

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTopWhite, colorBottomWhite]
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = uiView.bounds

    uiView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

I know I can do it in a more generic way, and change the way I am handling the colors, but it's not the point, it is for testing purpose for now.

I tried to call it like this :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()
     UIUtils.setGradientWhite(uiView: self)
}
```

The gradients do not accumulate this way, in the awakeFromNib, BUT, the animation isn't finish and I only have half of my cell with gradient applied.

And if I do it in this method :

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()

     CATransaction.begin()
     CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
     UIUtils.setGradientWhite(uiView: self)
     CATransaction.commit()
}
```

The gradient animation is properly finished, applying to the whole view, but when the cell is reloading, it applies a new gradient on top of the previous one, until I cannot see my cell anymore (in this case too much white here).

Any ideas on how can I solve this issue?

Comment: It's accumulating because of the reuse. Instead, keep the code in `awakFromNib()`, but in `override func layoutSubviews()`, instead do guard `if let gradientLayer = self.layers.first as? CAGradientLayer() { gradientLayer.bounds = self.bounds }`.

Comment: Any reason why not to have a variable,`didSetupGradient = false`, set it to `true` once you add the gradient, and put the gradient adding code in `if !didSetupGradient`

Comment: By default function parameters are passed by value, not the reference. Hence it is not reflecting with the actual outside object. try to add "inout" keyword before "(uiView: inout UIView)'. or add return type and set updated object with existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews() 
   if !(self.layer.sublayers?.first is CAGradientLayer) { 
       CATransaction.begin()
       CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
       UIUtils.setGradientWhite(uiView: self)
       CATransaction.commit()
   }
}
```

Comment: This version is working. Thank you. As mentioned in the comment, I just needed to apply the gradient only once. Not multiple times in each reuse.